# data.table with data.frame parameter creates extra column

Tags: r, data.table

When I create a string column using data.table, using the data.frame parameter stringsAsFactor = F, the resulting data.table uses stringsAsFactor = F parameter correctly, but then the adds an extra column "stringsAsFactor".  It is easy enough to get rid of the extra column.  But is there a way to tell data.frame not to add columns based on the data.frame parameter?  I.e., is this a bug or a feature?  See ToyExample below:

```
library(data.table)
factorTest <- sample(c('O','A', 'B','AB'), 50, replace = T)
summary(factorTest)
   Length     Class      Mode 
       50 character character 
summary(as.factor(factorTest))
 A AB  B  O 
10 18  7 15 
test1 <- data.frame(dabo = factor(factorTest, 
     levels = c('O','A','B','AB')), dabostr = factorTest, 
     stringsAsFactors = F)
test2 <- data.table(dabo = factor(factorTest, 
     levels = c('O','A','B','AB')), dabostr = factorTest, 
     stringsAsFactors = F)
summary(test1)
 dabo      dabostr         
 O :15   Length:50         
 A :10   Class :character  
 B : 7   Mode  :character  
 AB:18                     
summary(test2)
 dabo      dabostr          stringsAsFactors
 O :15   Length:50          Mode :logical   
 A :10   Class :character   FALSE:50        
 B : 7   Mode  :character   NA's :0         
 AB:18
```

Comment: `data.table` simply don't have the `stringsAsFactors` argument- see `?data.table`. So you are basically just creating a new column. The reason the strings aren't converting to factors like `data.frame` is because it the default `data.table` behavior.

Comment: I've filled feature request to handle that or raise warning: [data.table#1446](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1446)

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [commit 3dbc493](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/3dbc493bc3cabd807d0ce89af16f4a80d7e3a592) and now `data.table()` has fully functional `stringAsFactors` argument.
When TRUE it will use fast internal *as.factor* function, as the base `factor()` is slow.
Below your code reproducible on latest data.table 1.9.7.

```
library(data.table)
factorTest <- sample(c('O','A', 'B','AB'), 50, replace = T)
test1 <- data.frame(dabo = factor(factorTest, 
     levels = c('O','A','B','AB')), dabostr = factorTest, 
     stringsAsFactors = F)
test2 <- data.table(dabo = factor(factorTest, 
     levels = c('O','A','B','AB')), dabostr = factorTest, 
     stringsAsFactors = F)
summary(test1)
# dabo      dabostr         
# O : 8   Length:50         
# A :10   Class :character  
# B :16   Mode  :character  
# AB:16                                   
summary(test2)
# dabo      dabostr         
# O : 8   Length:50         
# A :10   Class :character  
# B :16   Mode  :character  
# AB:16
```